# Хождение игрока по мешу из треугольников.(Surface nets)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, 3d

Про surface nets
https://0fps.net/2012/07/12/smooth-voxel-terrain-part-2/

Я реализовал этот алгоритм на с++.
[image: SN]

Теперь возникла проблема: дело в том, что мир является не плоскостью а планетой поэтому вектор гравитации постоянно меняется.
Каждый сектор планеты имеет 17x17x17 точек в которых <= 0 значит пусто иначе земля.
И надо как-то сделать хождение игрока по этой планете.
Какие есть способы проверки пересечения треугольника и сферы?
Как вообще можно реализовать хождение по треугольникам в 3D?

Comment: Вы можете делать всю землю вокруг игрока в некотором радиусе плоской и работать с ней как обычно.

Comment: Изменение ближайшего рельефа к игроку при хождении неприемлемо.

Comment: Уточните по какой причине? **указание ограничений позволит лучше найти более подходящее решение*

Comment: Изменять сам рельеф при хождении даст возможность проходить сквозь стены итд. вдобавок надо будет за игроком стелиться ровная дорога. И вообще так не делается(по крайней мере я невидел).

Comment: Если мир достаточно большой, то уплощение будет незаметно (например при радиусе 6371км, в большинстве применений, мы считаем пол плоским) и через стены никто не ходит.

Comment: А разве описанный в той статье способ не подходит? Вот он там и для сферы строит сетку, и для тора, и для каких-то загогулин.

Comment: уплощение будет заметно тк планета не плоская(иначе бы не надо было surface nets).
Причём тут постройка сетки? сетка есть(точнее треугольнички).

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос примерный радиус планеты, чтобы было ясно, что подходит, а что нет.